# Get FB ID with Facebook Graph Api

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

Please help to get FB id from Facebook Graph Api.

```
HttpsUtils httpsUtils = new HttpsUtils("https://graph.facebook.com/me");
    httpsUtils.addParam("access_token", accessToken);
    httpsUtils.addParam("fields", "username,name,first_name,last_name,gender,email,locale");
```

as a result I get some ID, which doesn't open FB page: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=xxx

Tell me how can I get FB ID.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> Tell me how can I get FB ID.

You got it already. (The app-scoped one, to be precise.)

> as a result I get some ID, which doesn't open FB page

That you can not open the profile any more using this id, is a different matter.

You need to ask the user for permission now to be able to get a working link that leads to their profile.

[`user_link`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v3.0#reference-user_link) is the name of the permission, and once you got that, you request the `link` field from the user profile.

Comment: curl -X GET \
  'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxxxxxxx&fields=id,user_link,link,name,first_name,last_name,gender,email,locale' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 62a6062c-df6e-4ca2-980f-cb53e41e89a7'     As a response I get:   {
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (user_link) on node type (User)",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "DpRO3uz/E/J"
    }
}

Comment: @Meri you are confusing the name of the permission with the name of the field …